# JavaScript orientation API dont work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, orientation

i want to move ball example from:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Detecting_device_orientation

I was trying to use accelometer or gyroskope.
The demo from mozilla works on my phone.
My demo don't works on the same phone - so its code fail i think.
Don't know why it doesn't work.
My Example link:

http://serwer2134873.home.pl/tests/orientation/index.html

So i created the same code:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">

            svg:not(:root) {
              display: block;
            }

            .playable-code {
              background-color: #f4f7f8;
              border: none;
              border-left: 6px solid #558abb;
              border-width: medium medium medium 6px;
              color: #4d4e53;
              height: 100px;
              width: 90%;
              padding: 10px 10px 0;
            }

            .playable-canvas {
              border: 1px solid #4d4e53;
              border-radius: 2px;
            }

            .playable-buttons {
              text-align: right;
              width: 90%;
              padding: 5px 10px 5px 26px;
            }
            .garden {
  position: relative;
  width : 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top   : 90px;
  left  : 90px;
  width : 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

        </style>
        
        <title>Detecting device orientation - Orientation_example - code sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="garden">
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>

<pre class="output"></pre>

        
        
            <script>
                var ball   = document.querySelector('.ball');
var garden = document.querySelector('.garden');
var output = document.querySelector('.output');

var maxX = garden.clientWidth  - ball.clientWidth;
var maxY = garden.clientHeight - ball.clientHeight;

function handleOrientation(event) {
  var x = event.beta;  // In degree in the range [-180,180)
  var y = event.gamma; // In degree in the range [-90,90)

  output.textContent  = `beta : ${x}\n`;
  output.textContent += `gamma: ${y}\n`;

  // Because we don't want to have the device upside down
  // We constrain the x value to the range [-90,90]
  if (x >  90) { x =  90};
  if (x < -90) { x = -90};

  // To make computation easier we shift the range of
  // x and y to [0,180]
  x += 90;
  y += 90;

  // 10 is half the size of the ball
  // It center the positioning point to the center of the ball
  ball.style.top  = (maxY*y/180 - 10) + "px";
  ball.style.left = (maxX*x/180 - 10) + "px";
}

window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);

            </script>
        
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed SSL connection protocol (https).
Doesn't expect that :)